# Fix Windows 8 bootloader after converting MBR disc to GPT

Tags: windows-8, bootloader, uefi

I bought a new MoBo, processor, and some 3TB HDDs last week and am currently setting up a clean installation of Windows 8 on the machine.

The MoBo is an Asus RoG Maximus VII Ranger (What?! It was decently-priced. And shiny. o.o) with the on-board Intel Rapid Storage Tech semi-hardware-RAID thingy. I've configured a RAID5 array with three of the 3TB disks (I'm already aware that a three-disk array with large drives isn't ideal, but I plan to rectify that later by expanding the array).

Windows 8 installed successfully on the resulting 5.4TB array (on the third attempt… >:/) using an MBR partitioning table. Once the machine was running and I'd installed all the hardware drivers for networking, etc, on it, I used AOMEI Partition Assistant to convert the disk to use GPT. This succeeded, and upon rebooting the UEFI bootloader throws an error complaining that a required device is missing, which I expected.

I'm currently booted to the Windows 8 Install DVD in order to fix the problem. After loading the IRST RAID driver, I used `diskpart` to list the volumes on disk 0, which correctly showed the 350MB boot partition created by the installer, and my 5.4TB C:\ partition.

When I run `bootrec /scanos`, it gives the following output:

```
Successfully scanned Windows installations.
Total identified Windows installations: 1
[1] C:\Windows
The operation completed successfully.
```

However, when I run `bootrec /fixboot`, I receive this error:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I get the same error from `bootrec /rebuildbcd`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are missing the 100 MB EFI partition in the beginning of the hard disk. This partition should be formatted as FAT32 and should have the EFI GUID. This is where the EFI boot files are stored and where the BIOS will look for them (based on the fixed GUID). I'm posting this as a comment because I've never restored an EFI system so I don't know if the command (`bootrec /fixboot`) still applies. It probably can be fixed by booting from a GParted live CD and creating the EFI partition (file system type EFI should take care of the GUID) and then try the command again. But why not just reinstall?

Comment: Thanks, Louis. I'm guessing this is different to the 350MB partition the installer creates, which just contains an EFI directory in it? (Edit: Right, no newlines… thanks, SE. >.<) There's a Boot and Microsoft\Boot directory inside that which look like they contain the EFI boot data. see: http://i.imgur.com/XHvn7o9.png

Comment: Yes, I did a quick search and [here](http://www.eightforums.com/general-support/21717-question-windows-8-reserved-partition.html) it states that the 350 MB partition is used for the boot manager, recovery system and some other stuff. However, the boot manager won't do anything on its own. Just like MBR, the EFI files are just some kind of pointer to the bootloader (a bootloader for the bootloader, lol).

Comment: Oh, I see you've edited your comment. I'm not completely sure now. The partition should be formatted as FAT32 for EFI. I always have a 100 MB and a 350 MB partition. I'm on my phone so I can't really check it now. Better wait for someone else or I'll take a look when I get home.

Comment: Incidentally, I don't get the option to install using GPT in the Windows 8 installer, hence the ridiculous process. Apparently it's the first thing the 8.1 installer asks, but I can't use that DVD image to install because I have a 8.0 product key. >.<

Comment: You'll probably have 2 boot options in the BIOS: `CDROM` and `EFI: CDROM`. Use the second one to make the installer use GPT. For the 8.1 problem there's an easy fix. Search for Windows 8.1 placeholder keys. You'll get another SuperUser page with these keys. Use one of them, and change the key after installation. I can confirm this works perfectly. This is completely legal because the keys are just placeholders.

Comment: Oh, I wish I'd known about that 6 hours ago when I started this bloody process! xD Also, cheers. :)

Comment: Going to try the EFI DVD boot option. Shame to waste all the time setting up the drivers, etc, but eh.

Comment: Yep, comes up recognising the partitions instantly. Stupid mistake, not noticing that it wasn't using the UEFI boot option. >.< Will leave this up though as it may be useful for someone else who can't just blank and start again. Also, it's useful to know how to fix this error if it comes up in the future.

Comment: Cool! Mind if I repost my comment as an answer so you can accept it when I get home?

Comment: Yup, go ahead. :) I'm also hoping I'll get the actual answer on how to do it, though, because as I said above, it's useful to know. Incidentally, when installing using the UEFI boot option from the DVD, the installer does indeed create two extra 100MB partitions. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to split the 350MB MBR boot partition into the System and Reserved partitions used by the Windows GPT boot system.

Based on instructions I wrote last time I did this process:

Load a command prompt from the DVD (Repair Your Computer -> Troubleshoot -> Advanced options -> Command prompt)

```
diskpart
select disk 0
list partition # To verify layout
   Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
   -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
   Partition 1    Primary            350 MB  1024 KB
   Partition 2    Primary            126 GB   350 MB
select partition 2
assign letter=C
select partition 1
delete partition
create partition EFI size=100 offset=1
format quick fs=fat32 label="System"
assign letter=S
create partition msr size=128 offset=103424
list partition
    Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
    -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
    Partition 1    System             100 MB  1024 KB
    Partition 3    Reserved           128 MB   101 MB
    Partition 2    Primary            126 GB   350 MB
exit
bcdboot c:\windows /s s: /f UEFI
```

Now reboot. Hit the BIOS and enable UEFI booting. Hopefully Windows will now load.

Comment: I got an error while trying to delete the partition. "delete partition **override**" helped for me.

Comment: Bounty worthy. You saved my boot.

Comment: Brillian! I did a P2V conversion with Disk2vhd, then attached it to Hyper-V but the system wasn't booting. The "regular" bootrec /tryEveryOptionUntilOneWorks failed. Your answer saved my day, thanks!

Comment: Saved my day too. I stupidly ignored gpggen's warning as I thought I'll be able to fix boot records before reboot anyway, but when I hit disk management, Windows went to bluescreen immediately followed by reboot to unbootable drive. This helped a lot, thank you!