# Got "No bootable device" after converting disk using mbr2gpt and switching to UEFI

Tags: windows-10, bios, uefi, mbr, gpt

I have a windows 10 laptop, and I wanted to convert my MBR hard disk to GPT so I can switch from Legacy BIOS to UEFI (I made sure that my laptop supports UEFI).

I ran mbr2gpt.exe and the conversion was completed successfully. I restarted my laptop and pressed F2 to access the BIOS, and from there I switched to UEFI. I saved and the changes and exited the BIOS and got the message "No bootable device -- Please restart system". (See [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWhUn.jpg))

I booted to lubuntu from a USB stick to check my hard disk, and found that everything was in place. All files are there and intact and there were no changes in partitions. I ran `sudo parted -l` from the terminal and here is what I got:

```
lubuntu@lubuntu:~$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA HGST HTS545050A7 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  376MB  375MB  ntfs               msftdata
 2      376MB   195GB  194GB  ntfs               msftdata
 3      195GB   195GB  105MB  fat32              boot, esp
 4      195GB   500GB  305GB  ntfs               msftdata
```

As you can see, the conversion was successful and the partition table is gpt now. Before the conversion, I had 3 partitions (The first 375MB system partition, 195GB C partition, and 305GB D partition). Moreover, the new 100MB fat32 efi partition is there (in contrast to [this case](https://superuser.com/questions/781282/fix-windows-8-bootloader-after-converting-mbr-disc-to-gpt)), and from what I read on the internet, it really does not matter if it is the first partition or not as long as it is in the first 2TB.

So, what is wrong? Why can't UEFI recognize the boot partition?

**Edit:** I found a folder called EFI in the D partition that did not exist before. It has the following structure:

```
/EFI
  /Boot
    /bootx64.efi
/Microsoft
  /Boot (Several files)
  /Recovery (too many files and folders inside)
```

**Edit 2:** My laptop is an old Toshiba Satellite C50. Here are two images from inside the BIOS: [image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPbCM.jpg), [image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POdG0.jpg).

Comment: You seem to have ended up with two EFI partitions. Try to boot into the UEFI/BIOS and change the boot device to the other disk. What model is your laptop? Have you taken good backups before doing this?

Comment: Your firmware must be reconfigured. See: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/mbr-to-gpt UEFI boots from GUID of ESP partition. Conversion changed/created both GUID & new UUIDs. And system has to be changed to boot in UEFI boot mode.

Comment: @harrymc Which one is the second EFI partition? Do you mean the 300GB D partition? How could that be, since an EFI partition should be fat32 esp? Also, I don't have another disk. For the model, see Edit 2, and I have taken a backup of all the important files.

Comment: @oldfred Could you please elaborate further on firmware reconfiguration?

Comment: Choose the other drive than the one selected, whatever partition that is displayed on it. If there is only one disk shown in the list, then don't do anything.

Comment: If you had BIOS/MBR before, your system was configured for BIOS boot. You now have to reset UEFI/BIOS to boot in UEFI mode & have Windows install .efi boot files into /EFI/Microsoft & update UEFI boot entry to use those files. I have never done it, but believe it is just running the standard Windows repairs, using a Windows repair/recovery drive booted in UEFI mode. You may also need /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi where bootx64.efi is just a copy of Windows .efi boot file. And whatever Windows repairs do to update BCD.